# Todo List with Email Functionality

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a todo list that has the ability to email you the list you just created at the click of a button. The todo list itself was made in React and it stores the inputs in your local storage. The functionality I'm looking to add would be on page load, or when you click a "Email" button a modal will prompt you to add your email, which will also be stored locally, and then it would send you the email of the list you just created for yourself.

Would I need to integrate an email api or a backend of some sort or is it possible to do this purely in the front end?

Here is the repo for the todo list itself:

https://github.com/GSometimes/Mini-Projects/tree/main/react-todo-list

Thank you.

Comment: Browsers do not contain any functionality to send email directly. At best, you can open a `mailto:` link that will open the user's default email client. If you want your application to send an email on its own, then yes, you need some sort of backend or third party API to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to setup a local smtp server that can send emails or use third party api like sendgrid or twilio.

a quickstart guide for sendgrid - https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-nodejs/#starting-the-project